# Instagram API Filtering Media by media_type

Tags: python, facebook-graph-api, instagram-api, instagram-graph-api

I'm using `facebook-python-business-sdk`

I'm trying to get the insights from an Instagram media alongside the media info.
I found that the media can have three type of `media_type`: `IMAGE`, `VIDEO` and `CAROUSEL_ALBUM`.

Each type has its own list of [insights](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-api/reference/ig-media/insights); the problem is that I cannot put all the metrics in one call because the response will raise an exception like this:

```
    "message": "(#100) Incompatible metrics (carousel_album_reach) with single post media",
```

By doing some attempts I have found that you can filter by `media_product_type` in this way:

```
ig_user.get_media(fields=["media_product_type{FEED}"])
```

but this is not helpful because I still have no information about the `media_type`; moreover, if I try this:

```
ig_user.get_media(fields=["media_type{VIDEO}"])
```

the field will be ignored.

Also looks like that this endpoint does not support the `filtering` param.

Is there any chance to filter by `media_type`?